# Can I change the compression level of ZipArchive?

Tags: php, zip

Is it possible to change the compression level and/or method used by the `ZipArchive` class?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is currently not possible, according to the [open <strike>bug report</strike> feature request on php.net](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41243).

Comment: Just in case anyone is still looking, this functionality does not yet seem to be implemented in PHP core's ZipArchive (as of mid-2012). I plan to use [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) and "zip -rn .jpg:.gif:.png images images", but this may not be ideal for all situations.

Comment: i wonder if it's really that hard to just add the feature and/or fix the bug. couldn't this be done by one single person within a few days?

Comment: This feature is available as of PHP 7.0.0, see
<https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/3a55ea02>.

Comment: It's implemented with the setCompressionIndex method: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setcompressionindex.php

Answer (score 9):

It seems to have been implemented / added to redistribution files in PHP 7: [ZipArchive::setCompressionName](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setcompressionname.php) and [ZipArchive::setCompressionIndex](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setcompressionindex.php). Not tested.

PS: The reason why it is set individually for files and not the entire archive is because files inside a ZIP archive are actually themself ZIP files and are just "glued" together to one "master ZIP archive".

Answer (score 7):

As stated in previous post, you can't do it with Zip.
If specifying a compression level is more important than the archiving method, then PHP zlib allows it:

```
string gzcompress  ( string $data  [, int $level = -1  ] )
```

$level - The level of compression. Can be given as 0 for no compression up to 9 for maximum compression.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is not possible evenin 2014 so i had to use the "exec" function with the zip command for linux :

```
exec("cd \"".$the_directory_you want_to_zip."\" && zip -0 -r \"".$path_zip."\" .");
```