# PHP library for creating uncompressed zip archives?

Tags: php, zip

This [Zip library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) does not allow to specify compression level. I am wondering if there are other php libraries allows create uncompressed zip archives? My application requires archiving multiple JPEG files into one big file and thus it makes no sense for compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just thinking to an other solution. You can try to use Zip command-line executable through `exec()` PHP function

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Zlib library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php). It's allow you to define compression level from 0 (no compression) to 9

Comment: If you really use Zip format, it's not possible yet. [Already anwsered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833168/can-i-change-the-compression-level-of-ziparchive)

Comment: Any other suggested format? I assume zip is most popular.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually possible to specify amount of compression with zip.  You can do it with  gzcompress, if you don't mind .gz format output, but there shouldn't be **that** much performance penalty in zipping up a JPEG anyway.

.gz is a popular open source archive format, and you can specify compression level like so:

```
$data = gzcompress  ( $data, 0 );
```

Edit: If you want to automate archiving *many files* at once without compression, you could try tar.  PHP:Pear has an excellent module for creating and unpacking tar archives.

Comment: In my case, users choose photos they want to download as zip. Since most users are familiar with zip format so it would be better to stay with zip. I just think that trying to compress JPEG files is a waste of resources since it saves little storage/bandwidth if any.

Comment: Zip is definitely the best choice if your users are going to be downloading the files.  Your best bet is probably (again) PHP:Pear's File_Archive module: http://pear.php.net/package/File_Archive