# PHP ZipArchive Compression

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am using the PHP ZipArchive class to create a ZIP archive. The archive will contain already compressed ZIP files. As such, there is no use compressing already compressed ZIP files and this will only add unnecessary overhead. Is it possible to create a ZIP archive with ZipArchive but not compress the files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the compression level of ZipArchive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833168/can-i-change-the-compression-level-of-ziparchive)

Comment: If available you should use the commandline zip tool for that (with `zip -q0` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the compression level with ZipArchive is not currently possible.  You can set the compression level with the Zlib library as long as you don't mind creating .gz files instead of .zip

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zlib.php